# How to authenticate without sending my username and password for HTTP requests?

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, teamcity

Currently, following is how I am sending request from PS to update a parameter:

```
$pair="$("username"):$("password")"
$encodedCreds=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue="Basic $encodedCreds"
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", $basicAuthValue)
$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'text/plain')
$headers.Add("Origin", 'https://teamcity.server.io')
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $updated_version
```

But I do not want my username and password mentioned like this anymore.
What other ways do I have to authenticate myself for HTTP requests made within from TeamCity Build Step through PS?

Comment: Based on the documentation (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-RESTAuthentication) it looks like basic auth is your only option short of allowing guest access.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use the basic auth but instead of using my own credentials used a super user created by the dev ops that is available to everyone in the company.